# How to select only fieldname when using show columns query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I use this query to select fields in a given table. Is it possible to select only the fieldname and not the whole structure of the table?

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM student
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're trying to determine the table structure? You can query MySQL's `information_schema` database directly for the fieldnames:

```
select COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='student';
```

Comment: thanks, I never thought that I can actually use the information schema database

Comment: Is it possible to specify the database? What if I have another database which has a table called student. It will also show up right?

Comment: Yes. There's a 'TABLE_SCHEMA' field in that table as well which is the database name.

Comment: put distinct before column_name would be effective.

Answer (score 1):

The solution mentioned here earlier is not the correct one. Example:

```
CREATE DATABASE db1;
CREATE DATABASE db2;
CREATE TABLE db1.t ( id_1 INT);
CREATE TABLE db2.t ( id_2 INT);
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME  ='t';
```

This will display:

```
+-------------+
| COLUMN_NAME |
+-------------+
| id_1        |
| id_2        |
+-------------+
```

suggesting that the table `t` has two column which is obviously not true. This query lists all the columns of the tables called `t` in *all* of your databases.

Instead, you should specify which database contains the table `t` you want to select the column names from:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
    WHERE 
        TABLE_NAME = 't' AND 
        TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db1';
```

Answer (score -3):

select COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME

FOR EXAMPLE: ROLLNO is a column_Name of table Student....

select ROLLNO from Student

Comment: -1 You completely misread the question. He is not asking to select one column he asking how to select a column from the table schema: `information_schema`

Comment: The question was about taking column names from specyfic table. Not the data for given column name.